# names for repetitive sequences

Tags: adverbs

The words once, twice, thrice describe the number of repetitions in a series of such repetitions or possible repetitions. I have searched several authoritative dictionaries & thesauruses without finding other examples. Does anyone know further single words in this sequence?

Answer (score 2):

There are no more in the sequence, other than (unofficially, for humorous effect, ["frice"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frice), which I've never even heard used.) Even "thrice" is rarely used (other than somewhat ironically.)  Instead, one just says "three times", "four times", etc; or, informally, "for the umpteenth time [clean your room!]" (or such, usually a parent to a teenager).

A list of (some) frequency adverbs can be found here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_frequency_adverbs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat complete list:

> once (1)
>   twice (2)
>   thrice (3)
>   quadtrice (4)

Comment: it should be spelled *quadrice* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-containing-quadrice this doesn't mean that it an acceptable term. I've never heard anyone use that word. Ever.